# "Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem" when trying to open a disk partition with debugs

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, debugfs

I'm trying to trace some I/O on my Linux virtual machine. The capture gives me LBAs which I need to map to the file name. I'm trying to use debugfs for that.

For example, I want to see what file LBA=41882816 belongs to. Here is what I have from fdisk:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 39.7 GB, 39728447488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4830 cylinders, total 77594624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a524d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2         1026048    77594623    38284288   8e  Linux LVM
```

so based on that I think it's in /dev/sda2.

Then I run debugfs to do the lookup but it won't open /dev/sda2:

```
sudo debugfs
debugfs 1.43-WIP (20-Jun-2013)
debugfs:  open /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem
```

Somewhere on the internet I found advice to run sync prior to that -- but it hasn't made any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Nikolai

Comment: /dev/sda2 isn't the filesystem. Your filesystem should be  in a dm block somewhere in /dev/mapper/

Comment: Thanks, that was it.